# Cider not fermenting I may have caused a problem

Tags: yeast

Hello I am new to home brewing and think we may have made a mistake in the process.
We chopped and squezed our apples that gave us 17 litres of juice this is now in a fermenting bucket to this we added Campden tablets.
After 24 hours I added a 9 gram sachet of Mango Jacks M02 cider yeast by sprinkling onto the juice as per the instructions on the pack a day later there is no activity.
I have since looked at the Amazon web site where I got the yeast and it says I should have mixed it with water and sugar.
Is there a way of starting the fermantaion.

Answer (score 1):

Really, the only way to be sure the yeast is/isn't doing anything is to get a hydrometer or refractometer and measure the must content over the course of a few days. If the gravity is dropping, you're fine.

A refractometer is quicker, but as the alcohol content increases, the reading becomes less accurate.

I've had yeast outlive potassium metabisulfite before so adding more yeast may help. I would consider trying a co-pitch of something more hearty like Kviek Lutra but not sure how well that plays with Mangrove Jack. Kviek is super buff though.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should be fine just sprinkling it on top of the juice.

No activity: do you mean there is no activity in the juice, or is there no activity in your airlock?

How much Campden tables did you add? The normal amount of metabisulfite to add, to inhibit oxidation, is 0,04 g/l. One Campden tablet would be enough. But normally you would not do that before adding your yeast.

I had the same problem last year, added too much metabisulfite, which killed my yeast. But the amount I used was around 10g, I think.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply.

Comment: There is no acttivity in the airlock and the juice looks the same

Comment: I used this recipe https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/howto/guide/how-to-make-cider

Comment: @ChrisClaydon: three Campden tablets looks like much, and also the instructions say to wait 24h before adding the yeast. Did you do it this way? How long is it now since you added the yeast.?

Answer (score 0):

It needs oxygen. Pure O2 and a stone is best or aerate mechanically. Yeast skipped growth phase but probably not dead yet.